In what cases is FindAndDelete useful?
In the non-segwit case, FindAndDelete removes signature data from scriptCode.
In P2PKH, the signature is not included in the scriptPubKey, so I think the only thing that may actually have signature data removed by FindAndDelete is redeemScript for P2SH.
But is there actually a useful use case for including a valid signature within a redeemScript? What was the intention behind introducing the FindAndDelete process?
In the following Bitcoin Core's FindAndDelete test case, the public key is recovered from the signature and set to scriptSig.
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v28.0/src/test/data/tx_valid.json#L496
